# Navigating to XAML View causes "The parameter is incorrect" error

Tags: uwp-xaml, template10

In my App.xaml.cs file, I am able to navigate to the view in question without error.

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.LogItemSearchPage));
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But, w hen I navigate to the view through the hamburger menu, I get the error.

```
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo AutomationProperties.Name="Search"
                                  ClearHistory="True"
                                  PageType="views:LogItemSearchPage">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                        Height="48"
                        Symbol="Find" />
            <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Search" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
```

As usual, this used to work fine, but somewhere along the line the error showed up.  The page does not need a parameter passed in and the ViewModel OnNavigatedTo method does not use one.

Comment: Disregard this question, I was not properly initializing the DateTimeOffset properties.